# How to print all the ways to cut off a string - combination

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tail-recursion, recursive-datastructures, recursive-backtracking

input: "abcd"
output: a list of all the ways to cut off the string.

```
[ ["a", "bcd"],["a", "b", "cd"], ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  ["ab", "cd"], ["ab", "c", "d"], 
  ["abc", "d"],
  ["abcd", ""]
]
```

I want a recursive solution. Preferably Java but not need to be language specific.
Thank you!

Please notice "abd" "c" is not valid, because you cannot rearrange the order.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: This isn't code writing service... Show us, what you tried so far...

Comment: Suggestion: First enumerate the possible number of cuts (you can cut "abcd" in 1, or in 2, or in 3, or in 4). Then for every possible number *k*, you have to decide where to cut: enumerate all the possible *k*-tuples of indices where to cut the string.

Comment: You are missing `["a", "bc", "d"]` cut.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to solve this problem. Here is one of them

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Splitter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String string = "abcd";
        //You should add empty string as a base
        printAllSplits(string, 0, new ArrayList<>(List.of(new StringBuilder())));
    }

    static void printAllSplits(String s, int currentIndex, List<StringBuilder> list) {
        if (currentIndex == s.length()) { //reached the end, nothing left to split
            System.out.println(list);
            return;
        }

        //We should consider two decisions at each index: 1. split
        //                                                2. don't split

        //split here
        if (currentIndex > 0) {
            list.add(new StringBuilder(Character.toString(s.charAt(currentIndex))));
            printAllSplits(s, currentIndex + 1, list);
            //remove it not to affect a future call
            list.remove(list.size() - 1);
        }

        //don't split here
        list.get(list.size() - 1).append(s.charAt(currentIndex));
        printAllSplits(s, currentIndex + 1, list);
    }
}
```

You can modify this code to fit your needs. If you don't like or understand anything, feel free to ask. Also, if you need exactly a string, you can convert string builder to string at the end. I use string builder, because it's mutable.